# Populate ID by group using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I want to add a new object to an object with an existing ID and automatically add the maximum value to each group ID.(maximum value+1)

The expression I implemented is filled with the same maximum value for each group.
if( "node_id" is null, maximum( "node_id" , "Group" ), "node_id" )

When creating an object for the first time, a group without an existing ID is possible.
However, if an existing object has an ID, it is not possible to have to be +1 at the maximum value of the existing ID.
"Group" lpad(( array_find(array_agg( $id,   "Group"  ),$id)+1),5,0)

Is there a way to implement it automatically like the picture below?

[image]

Comment: What is "gaekchae"?

Comment: I want to add a new object to an object with an existing ID and automatically add the maximum value to each group ID.          gaekchae = object (Feature)                           Please understand that I am not familiar with English.

Comment: That's ok. I just didn't understand what it meant and couldn't find it's meaning with a basic google search.